# Android-start activity from service

Tags: android

My problem is:
I have Activity A, which starts a service S. A starts another application B, which is installed in the system. Then S starts activity B, at this very moment, B starts, along with A. Technically, A shouldn't start but it did. I'm so confused about this. I really hope someone would help me with this. I've spent hours on it.
Here's the code:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{

Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_b);

    intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
    //start an app in the system
    AppManager.getAppManager(this).launch(10);
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService(intent);
}

}

public class TestService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter onfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

    registerReceiver(screenon, onfilter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(screenon);
}

BroadcastReceiver screenon = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public static final String TAG = "screenon"; 
    public static final String Screen = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals(Screen))
            return;

        //start TestLockActivity when screen on
        Intent it = new Intent(TestService.this, ActivityB.class);
        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(it);
        return;

    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}

public class ActivityB extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_lock);
}
}
```

**launch() method in AppManager:**

```
public void launch(String activityName)
{
    ResolveInfo info = getResolve(activityName);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
            activityName));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent); 

}

public void launch(int idx)
{
    String activityName = getActivityName(idx);
    launch(activityName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Activity B already is attached to a running task (the one that is rooted in activity A). It is specified in the documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) too:

When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now
starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will 
simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in. See
[FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK) for a flag to disable this behavior.